# Display input and label same line with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to display, label and inputs on same line :

I tried in CSS:

```
form  label {
    display:block;
    float:left;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kY5LL/18/

Comment: your "Submit Query"-button looks nice !

Answer (score 4):

here it is

```
.span6{
overflow:hidden;
 display:inline;
}
.span6 label, .span6 input {
display:inline-block;
}
.span6 input {
width:70%;
margin-left:3%;
}
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kY5LL/153/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bootstrap 3.x:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputType" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Label</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity" placeholder="Input text">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ea9xv/)

Comment: @ismailsunni are you sure? it works for me in Firefox 37

Comment: Apologize. After I check it again, it seems that I need to resize the "result window" in the fiddle to make it work. Below my screenshot for both cases.
Not inline: http://i.imgur.com/PQaHOaE.png
Inline: http://i.imgur.com/9yxje01.png
My browser is Chrome 41

I want to un-down vote your answer now, but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in my script. I created a div container box and inside the container, a label left to an input element.

.
**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <label>Firstname</label>
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.container{
  overflow:hidden;
}
label{
    width:70px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
}
input{
  width:240px;
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

remove the class `input-block-level` given to `input` tag